# Rails gemfile version constraint issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gemfile

I have installed two versions of devise gem on my local machine namely devise(3.5.1) and devise(3.5.2).

In my gemfile i have included devise gem with pessimistic version constraint as shown below.

```
gem 'devise' , '~> 3.4'
```

dependencies for devise gem:

```
devise-encryptable-0.2.0 (devise (>= 2.1.0))
devise_invitable-1.4.0 (devise (>= 3.2.0))
devise_invitable-1.3.6 (devise (>= 3.2.0))
devise_security_extension-0.8.4 (devise (>= 2.0.0))
devise_security_extension-0.8.3 (devise (>= 2.0.0))
devise_security_extension-0.8.1 (devise (>= 2.0.0))
devise_security_extension-0.8.0 (devise (>= 2.0.0))
```

As per my research the meaning of this operator(~>) is that it will look for devise version >= 3.4 but <4.0 . But whenever i do bundle show in my project home directory it gives me error as `"Could not find devise-3.4.1 in any of the sources"`.

My question is why `bundle show` command is giving an error if there is devise gem version >= 3.4 is available and installed on my machine(in my case devise version 3.5.2).

Comment: Do any other gems have a dependency on 3.4.x?

Comment: @japed - No there is not dependency on 3.4.x .. see the updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Gemfile is locked on this version thats why your `bundle install` command will not look for a different version try run `bundle update devise` then Rails will try to look for a newer version of `devise` gem and update your dependency.

**understand the operator `~>`:**

when you add new gem into your Gemfile `bundler` have to take in account that you have dependency then the operator `~>` come into action it will try to find the completable version for all the gems listed in your Gemfile and will not be locked to specific version it will be locked to a range of version lower then the first digit.

**understand `bundle install`:**

`bundle install` command look for gems listed in Gemfile.lock and will not update OR change any gem version no matter which operator is in your Gemfile.

Comment: you are right... actually my gem was locked on version 3.4.1 and thats why i was getting error. after running bundle update devise gem version changes from 3.4 to 3.5.2